# ExtJS xml reader, tag name contains colon

Tags: extjs4, xmlreader

I'm trying to load data from xml file, but tag names contain colons. Results of given code aren't displayed.

```
    var auth = "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    // Create store          
    var xStore = new Ext.data.Store({
        autoLoad: false,

        // Override default http proxy settings
        proxy: new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
            // Call web service method using GET syntax
            url: 'http://myotherdomain.com/file.xml',
            headers : { Authorization : auth }
        }),

        reader: new Ext.data.XmlReader({
            record: 'aa:bb'
            },
            [
                {name: 'Name', mapping: 'name'}
            ]
        )
    });



    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: xStore,
        columns: [
            {header: 'Name', width: 120, dataIndex: 'Name', sortable: true}
        ],
        renderTo:'example-grid',
        width:540,
        height:200
    });

    xStore.load();
    grid.getView().refresh();
```

Here's some example data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<aa:bb>
   <name>simple_name</name>
</aa:bb>
```

On one forum I saw that it can be done with DomQuery, but I have no idea how to do this.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in version 4 of EXTJS implementation of DomQuery but not earlier versions. The code online shows you how to modify the code base prior to the namespace change in EXTJS 4.

See my post on

[extjs-4-2-escape-colon-in-xml-tag-for-xml-reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256425/extjs-4-2-escape-colon-in-xml-tag-for-xml-reader/20274445#20274445/)

Note that if the root tag uses a namespace you set it with a colon as the | namespace character applies after the definition of the namespace in the root xml tag.

i.e `root: 'atom:feed'` in the XML reader